# Same Method for different Subclasses

Tags: c#, generics, subclass

I have a `C#`-Class `Point` with two Subclasses `ColorPoint` and `AmountPoint`.

**Point-Class**

```
public class Point
{
    double x; // Position x
    double y; // Position y

    public Point(double pos_x, double pos_y) // Constructor
    {
        this.x = pos_x;
        this.y = pos_y;
    }
}

public class ColorPoint : Point
{
    double color; // White value (0 to 255)
}

public class AmountPoint : Point
{
    int amount; // Amount of Persons standing at this point
}
```

Now I want two things.

1. I want to have a method `AdaptMeshPoints` that accepts both `ColorPoint` and `AmountPoint` input-lists and I can change the common parameters of both (which are the parameters in `Point`)
2. I want to tell the method `AdaptMeshPoints`, which parameter of the Subclass it should print out.

This should than look something like this:

```
public class main
{
    public main()
    {
        List<ColorPoint> colorList = new List<ColorPoint>(4);
        AdaptMeshPoints<ColorPoint>(colorList, color);
    }

    public List<var> AdaptMeshPoints<var>(List<var> pointList, varType whatToPrint)
    {
        pointList[0].x = 45;
        Console.WriteLine(pointList[0].whatToPrint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if it can be done in both Java and C#, it would certainly be done differently. Pick a language. Ask two questions if you truly want answer for both languages.

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't expose variables in a class, expose only properties (which will allow you to implement read-only, read/write or write only (not that this type is common), and prevent external code messing with your values without your knowledge). Second, implement a .ToString in each of your sub-classes, then all you need to do is pass a Point object and .ToString() will cope with displaying it.

Comment: You could just pass `IEnumerable<Point>` and override `ToString` in the child classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is C# from the text in your question, even though your question is tagged with both C# and Java.

To be able to set `pointList[0].x`, you need to tell the compiler that `T` will always be a `Point` (or something which inherits from it). Do this with a generic type constraint (`where T : Point`).

You can also pass a delegate which describes which property you want to print:

```
public main()
{
    List<ColorPoint> colorList = new List<ColorPoint>(4);
    AdaptMeshPoints(colorList, x => x.color.ToString());
}

public List<T> AdaptMeshPoints<T>(List<T> pointList, Func<T, string> whatToPrint)
    where T : Point
{
    pointList[0].x = 45;
    Console.WriteLine(whatToPrint(pointList[0]));
}
```

Comment: Similar in Java, I guess, using a functional interface and a lambda expression.

Comment: Yeah, in Java I believe you'd have to use `T extends Point` and `Function<T, String>`

Comment: Well, `<T extends Point>`

Comment: Thx for your answer! `where T : Point` was the main thing, I had to implement :) how can I now add an item to the pointList? `mesh.Add(new T(0, 0));` does not work :/ ("Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint")

Comment: @Pixel_95 If `T` is a `ColorPoint`, what should `color` be set to? If `T` is an `AmountPoint`, what should `amount` be set to?

Comment: @canton7: just left as `null`

Comment: (Ignoring that fact that `int` and `double` can't be `null`...). It's probably easiest to pass in a factory, in the form of a `Func<double, double, T>`. E.g. `AdaptMeshPoints(colorList, x => x.color.ToString(), (x, y) => new ColorPoint(x, y))`

Answer (score 1):

**To 1.** Make a function that takes Point[]. Casting is automatically done if there is "no danger of Data loss" and such polymorphy cases are where this applies.

(I am not 100% certain if this is Polymorphy or falls more into the area of co- and Contra-variance. However the rules here are intentionally very similar).

**To 2.** This can be solved at least by:

- A extra parameter and a switch/case block
- Handing the function anotehr function or interface that holds the actuall code to access the variable
- Hand the code a Lambda or anonymous function to do the actuall work.

So you got to "pick your Posion".